# 500 Internal Server Error , ajax , setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-status-code-500

From my javascript file I am calling an interval function, here's the code

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON('/home/trackUnreadMsgs', function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      var temp = "#messby" + result[i].from;
      $(temp).css("background", "grey");
      //alert('hi');

    });
  });
}, 1000),
```

And here's the called function, trackUnreadMsgs in php.

```
public function trackUnreadMsgs() {
  $data['userData'] = $this - > session - > userdata('userData');
  $user_id = $data['userData'][0]['id'];

  $count_unread_msgs = $this - > data - > myquery("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE `to`=".$user_id.
    " AND status='unread'");

  $count_unread_msgs = json_encode($count_unread_msgs);
  print_r($count_unread_msgs);
}
```

Apparently everything runs fine on the browser(Chrome), but this is what the console is printing:

```
VM2800:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(anonymous function) @ seth_custom.js:225j @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2x @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/innov/index.php/home/trackUnreadMsgs 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ seth_custom.js:203
jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/innov/index.php/home/getAllUnreadMsgs 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ seth_custom.js:274
jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/innov/index.php/home/trackUnreadMsgs 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ seth_custom.js:203
jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/innov/index.php/home/trackUnreadMsgs 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ seth_custom.js:203
VM2805:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I want to know, what am I doing wrong ,why am I receiving this log & how to fix this. I am running this on localhost Wamp server.

Comment: *"500 Internal Server Error"* - Check your logs.

Comment: `}, 1000),` <-- what about this little guy at the end here?

Comment: *Please DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is meaningless for categorizing your question.* as per the tag description you of course have read when you added it.

Answer (score 0):

You set the wrong route in your AJAX request.
The correct path is

> $.getJSON('/innov/index.php/home/trackUnreadMsgs', function(result) { ... });

Comment: I am using codeigniter, & the protocol to access a php controller function is controllerName/functionName.

Comment: So you should edit your settings in codeigniter or hardcode the host where the system make the Ajax call because the root path is wrong